# Turn on camera on a device through Bluetooth from another device

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, bluetooth

I got an app request from a classmate who asked me if I could do an app so if I have 2 iPhones, iPhone #1 and iPhone #2. I get the app on both and connect them through e.g. Bluetooth. Then I can see the camera of iPhone #2 on iPhone #1's display. It should be possible because like GoPro and iON Air Pro have that, so you can stream the camera on your device. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think its possible .. Your app should be open in both **iPhones** and then when one **iPhone** will get any action from another **iPhone** then you can open its camera.. example:- When we export any file from one app to another then in second app file is import and in app delegate handleOpenURL: method calls and in this method we can do what we want .. so you can do same thing in bluetooth case. I dont have much idea about bluetooth so cant tell you exact code.

Comment: I need to do something like this. You get something?